# Detect a mouse click on an overlapping grid of boxes - JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse

I am currently trying to detect a mouse click on two grids of boxes simultaneously. One grid is easy, and I've just been using:

```
var gridPosX = Math.floor(mouseClickX/BoxWidth);
var gridPosY = Math.floor(mouseClickY/BoxHeight);
```

Now I also want to detect a mouse click on a secondary grid of boxes, located at the corners of the first grid of boxes. This could be achieved in a similar way to the first grid. The problem comes in because I want to detect a click on either the first grid, or the second one, at the same time. What is the best way to differentiate a click on the first grid verses a click on the second grid? I've tried to remove the Math.floor and used the greater than and less than operators (> <) to see if the click was closer to one grid spot than the other, but I've had no luck with that so far.

[**This is an image example of the grid. The black being the main one, the red being the second one**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtrPU.png)

```js
var WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 1280;
var canvas, context;
var grid = [];
var grid2 = [];

var gridWidth = 10, gridHeight = 10;
var boxWidth = WIDTH/gridWidth, boxHeight = HEIGHT/gridHeight;

function main(){
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = WIDTH;
  canvas.height = HEIGHT;
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  
canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
  if(e.which == 1){
    var gridPosX = Math.floor(e.offsetX/boxWidth);
    var gridPosY = Math.floor(e.offsetY/boxHeight);

    grid[gridPosX][gridPosY] = 0;
  }
}
  
  init();
  setInterval(draw, 30);
}

function init(){
   for(var x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++){
    grid[x] = [];
    grid2[x] = [];
    for(var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++){
        grid[x][y] = 1;
        grid2[x][y] = 1;
    }
  }
}

function draw(){
  for(var x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++){
    for(var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++){
      if(grid[x][y] == 1){
  context.fillStyle = 'gray';
        context.fillRect(x*boxWidth, y*boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight);
        context.strokeRect(x*boxWidth, y*boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight);
      }
    }
  }
  for(var x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++){
    for(var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++){
      if(grid2[x][y] == 1){
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fillRect((x*boxWidth)+(boxWidth)-(boxWidth/4), (y*boxHeight)+(boxHeight)-(boxHeight/4), boxWidth/2, boxHeight/2);
         context.strokeRect((x*boxWidth)+(boxWidth)-(boxWidth/4), (y*boxHeight)+(boxHeight)-(boxHeight/4), boxWidth/2, boxHeight/2);
      }
    }
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Do add some relevant code...

Comment: Quickly wrote an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the red grids show on top of the gray ones, I think you can first decide whether a mouse event is on a red grid or not. If not, then it must be on gray grids.

Based on the calculations below to check if a red grid is clicked:

```
      var xRedIndex = Math.floor((e.offsetX - 3 / 4 * boxWidth) / (boxWidth / 2));
      var yRedIndex = Math.floor((e.offsetY - 3 / 4 * boxHeight) / (boxHeight / 2));
      if (xRedIndex % 2 === 0 && yRedIndex % 2 === 0) {
        console.log("red");
        console.log("Red grid x: " + (xRedIndex / 2));
        console.log("Red grid y: " + (yRedIndex / 2));
      } else {
        console.log("gray");
        var gridPosX = Math.floor(e.offsetX / boxWidth);
        var gridPosY = Math.floor(e.offsetY / boxHeight);
        grid[gridPosX][gridPosY] = 0;
      }
```

Basically, you first subtract the initial gray area in the first column/row from the offsetX/Y, then see if the rest of the offsetX/Y contains an odd or even number of boxSize/2 (side length of red grid). An even number means the click is on red grids, otherwise it falls on the uncovered gray area.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwxzgth6/1/